# few name are not coming in reference (e. g. [20],[21] ) in latex, please help me

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

I'm unable to detect the problem regarding the absence of a few names in the reference (e. g. [20],[21] ). Please find the attached image.

Comment: They are probably other articles by Fornberg. The bibliography software chooses to represent them without repeating the name. If that's not the case, please edit the question to show us the TeX source.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some bibliography styles omit the name in case it would be repeated. Some of them can be tweaked to disable this behaviour, so please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) of your document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially, we need to know the bibliography driver that you use and see the BibTex entries of the problematic references.

Comment: @EthanBolkar yes, you are absolutely right they are the other articles by Fornberg. Is there any other way to make it visible?